# Count unique points in polygon Python Error

Tags: pyqgis

I need to count different values in a point shapefile field inside several thousands of polygons. I know the tool "Count unique points in polygons" and it works fine when I call it from the toolbox. But as I said, I have to use it in a lot of polygons, so I wrote this Python script:

```
import os, processing

# Set local variables
path = r'my\base\path\Dissolves'
continents = r'\somepath\points.shp'
outpath = r'path\to\outfile'

# Creamos la lista de shapes
shpList = [os.path.join(path, i) for i in os.listdir(path) if i.endswith('.shp') and not 'point' in i]
print('creada lista de', len(shpList), 'shapes')

for shp in shpList:

    outShp = os.path.join(outpath, os.path.split(shp)[1])
    print('Haciendo especie:', os.path.split(shp)[1])

    try:

        # Ejecutamos el join espacial dentro de un tr por si hubiera algun error poder continuar al siguiente shape
        processing.runalg('qgis:countuniquepointsinpolygon', shp, continents, 'issed',  'NUMPOINTS', outShp)

    except Exception as e:

        print('Error', e, os.path.split(shp)[1])
        continue
```

When I applied this code I don't get any error message, and I get the new polygons and everything seems to be ok. But I don't know why the higher value in the count unique values field ("NUMPOINTS") it never gets higher than 2, which is incorrect.

I tried the same polygons with the same points file, doing them one by one and doing them in the script, and get different values (I mean, all the values larger than 2 appears to be 2 in the script).

I edit this post to write the link to some shapes (just 5 and a part of the points in my Dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/f5982yd8dovsng3/AAAfwVmbtGc4uSOhi96GLHP4a?dl=0).

Comment: Looks like you may have `shp` and `continents` in the wrong order according to the [usage documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_analysis_tools/countuniquepointsinpolygon.html).

Comment: No, shp are the polygons where I am doing the loop and "continents" is the point shapefile. I have been proving and it seems that I get this error when the points are very numerous (continents.shp have more than a million). In few points, the tool works fine. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Oh yeah, I see that now.  I didn't see that part of your code.

Comment: @Digd I have just done a test and it seems that your scripts works: are you sure that all the layers have the same CRS?

Comment: Yes, they are in the same CRS. When I use a subset of all the points it works correctly, but when the points number is huge I get  2 like maximum value in the NUMPOINTS field (and I am sure that is not correct).

Comment: @Digd I created a test on a sample layer with 200 points, so maybe you should write a bug report. I can't do it right now, but I may try to provide you a PyQGIS code for accomplish the same take without recurring to the **Count unique points in polygon** tool. Would it be of interest?

Comment: @mgri Yes for sure, I'd be very interested! I have written a code to do this in pure python (shapely and fiona), but the process is too slow (I believe that the problem is that I have very big polygons, with a lots of inner holes). But I'd love to test your alternative PyQGIS code. And yes, I think that this is a bug (maybe a lack of memory amount?) because, as I said, it works fine with few points, but fails (just inside a loop, not one by one) with several thousands of points. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks as an understandable bug when processing **runalg** method is used in the loop. I can get a result by using **runandload** processing method. My code is the following:

```
import os, processing

path = '/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/test'
path_point = '/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/points_100000.shp'
outpath = '/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/test/output'

points_100000 = processing.getObjectFromUri(path_point)

shpList = [os.path.join(path, i) 
           for i in os.listdir(path) 
           if i.endswith('.shp') 
           and not 'point' in i]


for shp in shpList:

    outShp = os.path.join(outpath, os.path.split(shp)[1])
    print('Haciendo especie:', os.path.split(shp)[1])

    processing.runandload('qgis:countuniquepointsinpolygon', 
                          str(shp), 
                          points_100000, 
                          u'id',  
                          u'NUMPOINTS',
                          None)
```

I tried it out with a point shapefile with 100000 features (to save time) and 4 polygon shapefiles. After running the code at the Python console of PyQGIS, the count in each shapefile was obtained very fast. Results can be watched at next image (they were correct in all of these shapefiles). I hope that it helps.

[image]

Comment: A lot of thanks Xulnik, but it doesn't work. I am going to upload some shapes and some points to Dropbox, in case someone wants to test it.